# How to call in a method from another class for a dice roll game?

Tags: java, methods, counter, dice

I'm making a dice roll game where a user inputs a number 1-6 and then in another class there's a method that rolls a dice and counts the number of times it takes to get to the user's input. So, the coding for that class I have so far is:

```
package reviewGUI;

public class Die 
    {
    public static int dieRoll (int userNum, int count)
    {
        int die;
        
        die = (int)(Math.random()*6 +1); 
        
        while(die!=userNum)
        {
            count = count +1;
        }
        return count;
    }
    

    }
```

In another class, I call in that method with this code:

```
package reviewGUI;

import java.io.*;
public class UseDie {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        
        int userNum;
        
        int count=0;
        
        System.out.print("Enter a number from 1-6: ");
        userNum = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        
        while(userNum>6||userNum<1)
        {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid number, it must be between 1-6.");
            System.out.print("Please enter another number: ");
            userNum = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        }
        
        System.out.println("The number of times the program took to roll your number: " + dieRoll(userNum, count));
    }
}
```

I'm really new to creating methods and I think my main issue is the coding for calling in the "count" variable from my rolling dice method. Is there anyway I can fix this so the code will run?

Comment: Instead of ```dieRoll(userNum, count)```, try ```Die.dieRoll(userNum, count)```

Comment: And, when you implement danartillaga's suggested change, you will get an infinite loop.  Hint: In your `dieRoll()` method, look at the condition on your while loop.  What has to happen in order for that condition to change?  What happens inside the while loop?  Can it change the condition?

Comment: @danartillaga , Charlie Armstrong : Thank you so much! I changed it to Die.dieRoll(userNum, count) and moved the die= Math.Random and it works now thank you!!